# Can't access kmeans withinss value with Rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to update some old Python code from Rpy1 to Rpy2, but there's a couple lines that I can't get to run without error:

```
result = rpy.r.kmeans(datnorm, cls, kmeans_iterations, kmeans_nstart)
sse = sum(result['withinss'])
```

I updated the Rpy dependency to Rpy2 and refactored this code to use the Rpy2 `importr` to load the R stats module and `kmeans` function. This is what the code looks like after the change:

```
result = rstats.kmeans(matnorm, cls, kmeans_iterations, kmeans_nstart)
sse = sum(result['withinss'])
```

When this code runs, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Indices must be integers or slices, not <class 'str'>
```

I understand this is saying I can't use a string as an index because `kmeans` is returning an integer vector. How do I get the `withinss` value if the result isn't a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.rx2()` is probably what you want:

```
result.rx2('withinss')
```

(see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/vector.html#extracting-r-style)

Comment: Perfect! I eventually realized I could do `result[4]` to access the withinss total, but this is clearly the correct way.

Comment: Yes. It also works. To avoid surprises if the R library changes the order of the elements in `result` you can also do something like `result[result.names.index('withinss')]`